# flipping two coins when compared to a ball and bin situation?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, balls-in-bins

so as i have understood the sample space for the toss of two coins is

```
TT  
HH   
TH  
HT
```

even if the two coins are absolutely the same we can color each one different colors thus our sample must contain both TH and HT . so the possibility of getting exactly one H and one T is 1/2.

what about this problem :  we have two indistinguishable  balls and two different bins . what is the probability of each bin having exactly one ball. we show this by bars and stars like :

```
  1     * | *    
  2       | * *  
  3   * * |
```

and here we say that we have 3 possible out come ?!
so the probability is 1/3

but is not it the same as the problem of tossing two indistinguishable coins ?!

in the case of balls and bins cannot we again paint the balls ?
thus we have actually two out comes in number 1 .

Comment: I think you're exactly correct. If you paint the balls, i.e. different color stars, you would have two such scenarios matching your scenario 1.

Comment: so is the probability of each bin having exactly one ball 1/2 or 1/3 ?

Comment: i mean the painting cannot affect the probability ! but at the same time we learned in combinatorics that the number of ways we can distribute these 2 balls in 2 bins is 3 ?

Comment: It should be 1/2. No matter where the first ball is placed, there is a 50% chance the other ends up in the other bin.

Comment: Before we can calculate a probability, we need to produce a mathematical model of how the balls were placed into the bins. If the model involves throwing the balls one at a time, with equal probabilities of landing in Bin A and Bin B, then $1/3$ is simply wrong.Usually in applications such as caching, this is the appropriate model, and Stars and Bars is irrelevant.

Comment: would you please explain more why using stars and bars is incorrect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the balls in bins problem, there *are* three distinct events as counted by the "stars and bars" method.  However, each such outcome is not *equally probable*.  Their frequencies of occurrence carry a different weight.

In statistics you describe these *events* as the *macrostates of the system*.  They are composed of numerous (preferably) equiprobable *microstates*.  Basically, microstates are *outcomes* counted by considering distinctions which are ignored when identifying microstates.  (In this case, the distinctness of the balls.)

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{c|cc|c}\text{Macrostate} & \text{Microstates} & & \mathsf P(\text{macrostate})
\\ **| & AB| & & 1/4
\\ *|* & A|B & B|A & 1/2
\\ |** & |AB & & 1/4
\end{array}}$$

**Note:** In this model we don't find a need to consider the arrangement of the balls inside each bin; we are only concerned with the probability of balls entering bins, as only those outcomes contribute to the weight of the event.

---

In point of fact, this is exactly the same process involved in the coin scenario.  If we take the macrostate as the *count of heads showing*, and the microstates are the results of each individual coin toss.

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{c|cc|c}\text{Macrostate} & \text{Microstates} & & \mathsf P(\text{macrostate})
\\ 0 & \mathsf {TT} & & 1/4
\\ 1 & {\sf HT} & {\sf TH} & 1/2
\\ 2 & {\sf HH} & & 1/4
\end{array}}$$

**Note**  The microstates need not be equiprobable; but their probability weight needs to be accountable.  Suppose one of these coins was biased.  Then while these microstates would not be equi-probable, that bias could be accounted for.

---

**In summary:** When measuring probability of events, it is not sufficient to merely count distinct outcomes, you must also account for their individual probability weights.

Answer (score 1):

As André Nicolas succinctly explains, we would need to establish how the balls are distributed in the bins.  In other words, we need to clarify the probability distribution on the set of elementary outcomes.  If we consider the balls indistinguishable, that implies that what we are interested in are the **resulting configurations** of balls in bins, irrespective of how they were placed in the bins, in which case, there are three elementary outcomes:  $$(**,\;), (*,*), (\;,**).$$  If, however, we think of the placement of balls in the boxes as being independent events, in which each ball has an equal likelihood of being placed in either bin, then we must take into account the fact that the second elementary outcome described above is *twice* as likely to occur as either the first or the third.  While the balls are in fact indistinguishable, a convenient mental abstraction that helps us conceptualize this unequal probability is to color the balls or make them distinguishable.

Comment: regardless of which model we choose balls must act in a specific way in reality . meaning the probability of each bin having exactly one ball must be either 1/3 or 1/2 regardless of the model . should not it ?

Comment: If your interest in the balls and bins is along the lines of, "how many ways are there to put the balls in the bins," then the answer is three.  But if your interest is along the lines of, "what is the **probability** of observing a particular arrangement of balls in bins," then that depends on *how* the balls were placed in the bins.  Does that make sense?

Comment: so if we consider that the probability of a ball getting into each bin is 1/2 then using the stars and bars method to count the members of the sample space is wrong .

Comment: That is correct, because once you impose a probability on which bin a given ball is deposited into, and if you also have independence of ball distribution from other balls, you are concerned about much more than just how the resulting outcome looks.

Comment: so looking at the problem from the view point of probability switching between indistinguishable balls or distinguishable ones does not change the answer .  but when looking at the problem  from the view point of combinatorics switching between indistinguishable or distinguishable balls does matter .

Comment: can we even say that about all problems of probability and combinatorics ?

Comment: and again can we conclude that the stars and bars method should never be used to count the number of elements of the sample set in a probability problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Practically speaking
a. if you "throw" 2 balls (same or different color) into 2 bins that is equivalent to tossing 2 coins;
b. if you take a bin with 2 balls in a row and "throw" in a separator (which is forced to uniformly land left, centre, right) that is the bars+stars model.